# How to integrate C++ program/graphical UI to eclipse via plugin

Tags: java, c++, c, eclipse

I have a c++ program which analyzes media files and outputs its materials, so the graphical screen of this application program is complicated even like graph and diagram in stocks program. I am now want to develop eclipse plugin to integrate it to eclipse (NOT an external window), I know this is even impossible re-write the graphical UI though swing/awt, is any way I can integrate c++ program and UI to display in eclipse?

Thanks. any guidelines would be appreciated.

Comment: Q: Can I turn my standalone C++ GUI into an Eclipse plug-in?  A: Perhaps, but it sounds like it will be "challenging"?  Q: Can I make this hypothetical plug-in without Java and without Swing?  A: Probably not ;)

Comment: Forgive me, I didn't not much understood what you said..

Comment: Got to mention [JNI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Native_Interface), although it's the last solution I would look at.